# Wanted to know how to ftp the file from remote server

Tags: java, ftp

Can anyone help me how to ftp the file from the remote server (to which I have successfully established the connection?) I heard I need to have ftpclient.jar for ftp_ing the file to the local system(Windows). Is it so? If so can anyone help me in getting the jar please?

Comment: passionatebalu, you should use a headline that is a question, since this is a Q&A list, not an ordinary mailing list. So "Using java, how can a file be retrieved from a ftp server?" would be a much better headline.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a tutorial and various available libraries on that link: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.net` API:

```
URL url = 
    new URL("ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/file.zip");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
BufferedInputStream in = 
    new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream out = 
    new FileOutputStream("file.zip");

int read = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(data)) >= 0) {
    out.write(data, 0, read);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```